# Kubernetes cluster with incorrect DNS resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, resolv.conf, rancher-2

#### Question Description:

I have a harvester HCI Cluster (RKE2), where pods do not resolve the correct IP addresses for internet domains.

```
kubectl run debug --image=busybox -i --tty --rm -- sh

/ # ping serverfault.com
PING serverfault.com (<redacted IP address>): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from <redacted IP address>: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.362 ms
64 bytes from <redacted IP address>: seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.312 ms
64 bytes from <redacted IP address>: seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.319 ms
64 bytes from <redacted IP address>: seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.449 ms
64 bytes from <redacted IP address>: seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.317 ms
64 bytes from <redacted IP address>: seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.363 ms
64 bytes from <redacted IP address>: seq=6 ttl=63 time=0.296 ms
64 bytes from <redacted IP address>: seq=7 ttl=63 time=0.361 ms
^C
--- serverfault.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.296/0.347/0.449 ms
```

`<redacted IP address>` in this case happens to be the public IP address of the network in which the cluster resides in (and not one of `serverfault.com`s IP addresses).

However within the same container, `nslookup` does list the correct IP address:

```
/ # nslookup serverfault.com
Server:     10.53.0.10
Address:    10.53.0.10:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 104.18.23.101
Name:   serverfault.com
Address: 104.18.22.101

Non-authoritative answer:
```

This is not reproducible on the host node:

```
# ping serverfault.com
PING serverfault.com (104.18.23.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.18.23.101 (104.18.23.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=1.27 ms
64 bytes from 104.18.23.101 (104.18.23.101): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=1.30 ms
64 bytes from 104.18.23.101 (104.18.23.101): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=1.33 ms
64 bytes from 104.18.23.101 (104.18.23.101): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=1.29 ms
64 bytes from 104.18.23.101 (104.18.23.101): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=1.23 ms
64 bytes from 104.18.23.101 (104.18.23.101): icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=1.28 ms
^C
--- serverfault.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.231/1.284/1.333/0.030 ms
```

The cluster itself is a fresh installation of [`Harvester HCI v1.2.0`](https://harvesterhci.io/) with no additional configuration changes post-installation.

I am looking for further tips on how to troubleshoot this issue and find out why its resolving the wrong IP address.

---

#### Context:

`/etc/resolve.conf` on host:

```
### /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /var/run/netconfig/resolv.conf
### autogenerated by netconfig!

search harvester.<redacted domain> 1
nameserver 10.10.0.1
```

`/etc/resolve.conf` on pod container:

```
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local harvester.<redacted domain>
nameserver 10.53.0.10
options ndots:5
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` on host:

```
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#

passwd:     compat
group:      compat
shadow:     compat
# Allow initgroups to default to the setting for group.
# initgroups:   compat

hosts:      files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:   files dns

aliases:    files usrfiles
ethers:     files usrfiles
gshadow:    files usrfiles
netgroup:   files nis
protocols:  files usrfiles
publickey:  files
rpc:        files usrfiles
services:   files usrfiles

automount:  files nis
bootparams: files
netmasks:   files
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` on pod container:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

`/etc/hosts` in both cases contain no additional/suspicious entries.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be with the `ndots` option in `resolve.conf`:

```
options ndots:5
```

This option means that only if the hostname contains 5 or more dots it will not be appended to the search domain.

I suspect that this option is needed, because kubernetes internally uses a lot of hostnames with multiple dots.

However `serverfault.com` for example only has one dot, so I get appended to the local domain `harvester.<redacted domain>` making it `serverfault.com.harvester.<redacted domain>`. We happened to have a wildcard (`*`) record on that domain that pointed to the public IP address of the network. As a result `serverfault.com.harvester.<redacted domain>` would be resolved with the wildcard record, explaining that behaviour.

To fix this, we have temporarily removed DHCP record for the local domain. As a result, the `search` configuration in `result.conf` would no longer include it and thus internet domain would no longer appended to the local domain.

In the long we plan to remove the wildcard domain.